# How to send http request with multiple data arguments

Tags: python, http, flask, python-requests

With `flask_server.py` running:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, 
                    format='%(levelname)s-%(message)s')

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def route():   
    logging.info('get_json: %s : %s' % (request.get_json(), type(request.get_json())))
    logging.info('files: %s : %s' % (request.files, type(request.files)))
    return Response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

send the http `request` using `requests.post` method supplying it with Python `dictionary` as `json` argument:

```
import json, requests    
dictionary = {"file": {"url": "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py"}}  
response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/test", json=dictionary)
```

Flask server logs that it gets the dictionary with `Flask.request.get_json` method:

```
root - INFO - get_json: {u'file': {u'url': u'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py'}} : <type 'dict'>
root - INFO - files: ImmutableMultiDict([]) : <class 'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict'>
```

Again, via `requests.post` method's `files` argument send an open file object. Flask server will get it via `Flask.request.files` attribute:

```
files = {'key_1': open('/any_file.txt', 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, files = files)
```

Flask server logs:

```
root - INFO - get_json: None : <type 'NoneType'>
root - INFO - files: ImmutableMultiDict([('file_slot_1', <FileStorage: u'any_file.txt' (None)>)]) : <class 'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict'>
```

Lastly, send both: the `dictionary` and `open file` object using same `requests.post` method:

```
response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
                         json=dictionary, 
                         files=files)
```

Server logs that it gets the file but does not get the `json` dictionary.

Is it be possible to send a `request` supplying it with multiple data arguments: such as 'json' and 'files'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send [multiple file objects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files) using the `file` parameter and a list. However, your json data will need to be among one of those files. That's because even though you're just doing `json=dictionary` in the first request, it's actually sending `Content-Type: application/json` in the header. When you want to send multiple *parts*, you need to use `multipart/form-data`, via `files=<a list>`:

```
json_data = json.dumps({"file": {"url": "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py"}})
multiple_files = [
    ('targets', ('data.json', json_data, 'application/json')),
    ('targets', ('key_1', open('/any_file.txt', 'rb'), 'text/plain'))
]
response = requests.post(url, files=multiple_files)
```

The target's name here is assumed to be `targets`. You can make up your own if your Flask app is the recipient of the uploads.